# Why the limit of the Covariance function ensures stationarity of a process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, covariance, correlation

Given a Stochastic process $ x(t) $, I do not understand why the following definition of the covariance function ensures stationarity:

$ K_{xx}(\tau)=\lim_{t\to \infty}\Big( \mathbb{E}\big[ x(t+\tau)x(t)\big] - \mathbb{E}\big[x(t+\tau)\big]\mathbb{E}\big[x(t)\big]\Big ) $

Can anybody help me? 
I thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your definition of a stationary process ?

Comment: I mean wide-sense stationarity, i.e. when the process has constant mean and the covariance function only depends on the difference between two instants and not on the own instants, so in this specific case it would not depend on $t$, but only on $\tau$ .

Comment: Clearly, with this definition of Covariance function, if the above limit exists, then $K_{xx}(\tau)$ does not depend on $t$. But what about smaller times? Does stationarity still hold? Can such definition of covariance replace the usual definition?